# iPhone: more navigation controller in tabbar in container view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I'm working on a iPhone app with storyboard.
I need to put a TabbarController in a containerView like this:
[image]
The red rectangle in the controller on the left is a view I need to show always in the app.
I put 6 item in the tabbar so the tabbar show the "more" item.
When I tap on the "more" item I can normally customize the tabbar, but when I tap on "done" button nothing happens: the customization sheet don't disappear and I can't tap on the other items in the tabbar.
If I use the tabbar not in the containerView alla works fine.
Any help?
Thanks in advance!

Simone